# how to get output K.sqrt() in keras?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, backend

I feel confused when i use keras backend function sqrt().There is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(low=0,high=50,size=(4,3))
b = np.random.randint(low=0,high=50,size=(4,3))
a = K.variable(value=a)
b = K.variable(value=b)
prod = K.sum(K.batch_dot(a,b))
sqrt = K.sqrt(K.batch_dot(a,b))`
```

When I print(prod),the output is `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4491.0>`; when i print(sqrt),the output is `<tf.Tensor 'Sqrt_2:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32>`; I wonder why the output of sqrt doesn't have value of result (no **numpy= **  ) and how to get the value?

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

because it returns a tensor.  to get a value you need to use eval

```
K.eval(sqrt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you can get function from backend

```
k.backend.sqrt
```